# How can the enthalpies of liquification and vaporisation be different?

Tags: thermodynamics

If the enthalpy of liquification is not equal to the enthalpy of vaporisation, would that not imply that the heat required to make the same amount of mass undergo the phase change would be different depending on if the change is liquification or vaporisation?

It would then follow that the entropy change of the substance undergoing the phase change would be different in each case. 
However entropy is supposed to be a state function, so there seems to be a contradiction here.

Comment: The change in entropy in going from a solid to a liquid will definitely be different than the change in entropy in going from a liquid to a vapor.  All phase changes are not equal.

Comment: But if the two phase changes have the same endpoints, since entropy is a state function, the entropy changes should be have the same magntitude, no?

Comment: The three states are distinct:  solid, liquid, vapor.  I don't see the contradiction that you see.

Comment: State A is liquid state B is gas. Then going from A to B by vaporisation changes the entropy ofbthe system by some amount S1. going from B to A by liquidication has some associated entropy change S2. Since entropy is a state function, it should hold that S1=-S2.

Comment: The change in enthalpy going from a gas to a liquid will be minus the change going from a liquid to a gas (the enthalpy of vaporisation), but this tells you nothing about the change going from a liquid to a solid (the enthalpy of fusion)

Comment: Sorry I mixed vocabulary I meant liquification not fusion.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou It seems like you may be misinterpreting some values or something.  Enthalpy of vaporization is always the same in both directions.